# Python3.7 input() concatenating the integers

Tags: python

I have the following python code.

```
a = input("Enter first number") # 2
b = input("Enter second number") # 3

c = a+b # 23 instead of 5
print(c) # prints out 23 why?
```

I am using the following command to run python:

```
python3.7 filename.py
```

Instead of adding two numbers is concatenates two numbers and give me 23 instead of 5 even though I am using python3.7.

Every answer that I read says it evaluates and return the correct type:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-raw_input-and-input-in-Python#

Comment: `input()` always returns a string  by default. The fact you're using 3.7 is inconsequential.

Comment: `input()` returns strings, not integers. Try it with `red` and `rum`. Convert the strings to integers using `int(...)` around the `input()` call.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there are lots of articles on the web incorrect because they are suggesting that input evaluates and returns the correct type.

Comment: @johndoe `input()` in Python 2 calls `eval()` on the input. That's a terrible idea so it was dropped. No article on Python 3 would be correct if it suggests that's still the case - it's always a string.

Answer (score 1):

`a+b` concatenating string as `input` returns string. You need explicit type conversion to convert the input to integer using `int()` function.

```
a = int(input("Enter first number")) 
b = int(input("Enter second number"))
```